# confusions with 'this' keyword in nested functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, this

I have a doubt with javascript 'this'. I understand that 'this' refers to the object of the calling function. In example 1, if we are calling obj.bar(), why this.x = 4

```
var x = 4,
obj = {
    x: 3,
    bar: function() {
        var x = 2;
        setTimeout(function() {
            var x = 1;
            alert(this.x);
        }, 1000);
    }
};
obj.bar();
```

Output: 4

And in the following code, why this.x =3 and 1 later:

```
var x = 3;
var foo = {
    x: 2,
    baz: {
        x: 1,
        bar: function() {
            return this.x;
        }
    }
}
var go = foo.baz.bar;
alert(go());
alert(foo.baz.bar());
```

Output:
3,1

Comment: It's because you're calling it inside another function (the one that is passed to `setTimeout`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a variable at the very top level, you are creating a global variable in the `window` object. The keyword `this` at the top level refers to `window`.

```
var x = 4; // same as `window.x = 4`;
console.log(x); // same as `console.log(this.x)`;
```

When you call `obj.bar()`, the `this` keyword refers to `obj` inside of `bar`. But inside `setTimeout` you have a different `this`, the one that refers to the caller of the callback that you pass to `setTimeout`. This caller doesn't specify a value for `this`, so instead it just becomes the `window` object. Therefore, in this code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   var x = 1;
   alert(this.x);
}, 1000);
```

`this.x` is the same as `window.x`, which is `4` as you defined it above in the global scope.

Addressing your second example, when you assign a function to a variable you lose the context of where that function came from:

```
var go = foo.baz.bar;
```

Now when you call `go()` notice there is no dot in that call, which means there is no explicit object access, which means there is no implicit `this`. In this case you can still pass `this` by using `call`:

```
// outputs `3` because `this` is `window`, and `window.x` is `3`
// as declared in the global scope
alert(go());

// Will output `2` because `this` is `foo`
alert(go.call(foo));

// Will output `1` because `this` is `foo.baz`
alert(go.call(foo.baz));

// Will output `1` because the implicit value of `this` is `foo.baz`
// since we have an explicit object access in this function call
alert(foo.baz.bar());
```

You can avoid many of these issues with [use strict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). In strict mode, `this` will be undefined when not explicitly or implicitly defined, instead of defaulting to the `window` object.

Answer (score 3):

`this` is not determined when creating the function. It's determined when *invoking* the function.

In the case of setTimeout, the function is just being executed out of the blue, once a certain amount of time has elapsed. There is no context, so the browser invokes the function in the global context. You happen to have declared a global variable of `x=4`, so that's what this.x will equal. If you used strict mode (by adding `"use strict";` to the top of the script), then `this` would be undefined for the setTimeout case and you would get an error.

When you call `go()`, you have a standalone function with no context, so it's again being invoked in the global context. This results in it using your global x=3.

When you call `foo.baz.bar()`, you finally have a context. The context is `foo.baz`, so that's what `this` refers to, making `this.x` the equivilent of `foo.baz.x`, which equals 1.